# How to prevent component from re-rendering , react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, dropdown

So into the cartscreen, I am importing a dropdown component.

Now, there is a different dropdown inside the cartscreen called renderDropdown, and I'm using it to display two different data lists as two dropdowns for the user to choose from. Although this renderDropdown is functioning properly, selecting an imported dropdown causes the selected value in my renderDropdown to be cleared from the dropdown bar.

I verified that renderDropdown's value remains in the current state and I noticed that when I click on this imported drop-down, I get a message printed to the console(I have added console.log in cart screen whenever screen renders), which indicates that my entire screen is rendering. Could someone please look into this and let me know what's wrong?

Here is the code for a dropdown menu.

[I've also used the same component in a lot of other screens, and it works just fine]

```js
import { StyleSheet, View } from 'react-native'
import React from 'react'
import {  Dropdown} from 'react-native-element-dropdown'
import { COLORS } from '../constants'

const DropdownComponent = ({text, extractorValue, external_Id,  data:mainData, extraData, value, setValue, isFocus, setIsFocus,area=false, retailer=false, retailerC=false, extraStyling}) => {
  return (
    <View style={[styles.container, {...extraStyling}]}>
      <Dropdown
        style={[styles.dropdown, isFocus && { borderColor: COLORS.blue90 }]}
        placeholderStyle={styles.placeholderStyle}
        selectedTextStyle={styles.selectedTextStyle}
        inputSearchStyle={styles.inputSearchStyle}
        iconStyle={styles.iconStyle}
        data={mainData}
        containerStyle={{
          backgroundColor:COLORS.white10,
          borderRadius:10,
          marginTop:10,
          borderColor:COLORS.gray10,
          shadowColor:COLORS.blue90,
          shadowOffset:{
            height:15, 
            width: 15
          },
          elevation:19,
        }}
        search
        maxHeight={300}
        labelField={extractorValue ? extractorValue :"name"}
        valueField={external_Id ? external_Id :"name"}
        placeholder={!isFocus ? `Select ${text ? text : 'Item'}` : '...'}
        searchPlaceholder="Search..."
        value={value}
        onFocus={() => setIsFocus(true)}
        onBlur={() => setIsFocus(false)}
        onChange={item => {
          retailer ? 
          retailerC ?
          (
            setValue({...extraData, retailerClass:external_Id ? item[external_Id] : item.name})
          ):
          (
            ( area ?
              setValue({...extraData, area:external_Id ? item[external_Id] : item.name})
              :
              setValue({...extraData, route:external_Id ? item[external_Id] : item.name})
            )
          )
          :
          (
            setValue(external_Id ? item[external_Id] : item.name)
          ) 
          setIsFocus(false)
        }}
      />
    </View>
  )
}

export default DropdownComponent
```

and here is the cartScreen code which is causing trouble , also i want to include that i have to show 3 dropdowns on the screen so i was using the same component renderDropdown for all of them but i was having the same issue so i though it is because of third dropwdown (namely value scheme ) so i used external one but having the same issue.

```js
const CartDetailsScreen = ({navigation}) => {
    const [loading, setLoading] = React.useState(false)
    const {cartItems, setCartItems } = useContext(mapContext)
    const { createOrders, createOrderStatus, distributors, setDistributors, getDistributors, schemes, setSchemes, getSchemes} = useContext(commonUrlsContext)
    useLayoutEffect(()=>{
        navigation.setOptions({
            headerShown:true,
            headerTitle:'CART DETAILS',
            ...HeaderStyles, 
            headerLeft: () =>(
                <HeaderLeft navigation={navigation} />
            )
        })
    },[])
    const [valueSchemeFromDropDown, setValueSchemeFromDropDown] = React.useState('')

    React.useEffect(()=>{
        getSchemes()
        getDistributors()
        return () =>{
            setDistributors([])
            setSchemes([])
        }
    },[])

    React.useEffect(()=>{
        if(createOrderStatus){
            ToastAndroid.show('Order created successfully', ToastAndroid.CENTER)
            navigation.dispatch(
              CommonActions.reset({
                index: 0,
                routes: [
                  { name: 'OrderSuccessful' },
                ],
              })
            );
            setTimeout(()=>{{navigation.navigate('OrderSuccessful'), setCartItems([])}},1000)   
        }
    },[createOrderStatus])

    function RenderDropDown({index, text, data, external_Id, extractorValue, width, qtyScheme, valueScheme}){
        return(
          <View style={[styles.container, width && {width: width}]}>
            <Dropdown
              style={[styles.dropdown]}
              placeholderStyle={styles.placeholderStyle}
              selectedTextStyle={styles.selectedTextStyle}
              inputSearchStyle={styles.inputSearchStyle}
              iconStyle={styles.iconStyle}
              data={data}
              containerStyle={{
                borderRadius:10,
                marginTop:10,
                borderColor:COLORS.gray10,
                shadowColor:COLORS.gray90,
                shadowOffset:{
                  height:10, 
                  width: 10
                },
                elevation:15,
              }}
              search
              maxHeight={300}
              labelField={extractorValue ? extractorValue :"name"}
              valueField={external_Id ? external_Id :"name"}
              placeholder={`Select ${text ? text  : 'item'}`}
              searchPlaceholder="Search..."
              // value={qtyScheme ? cartItems[index]?.distributorName}
              onChange={item => {
                qtyScheme ?
                ( 
                  console.log(1),
                  cartItems[index].qtyScheme =  item[external_Id],
                  setCartItems(cartItems) 
                  )
                  :
                  (
                      console.log(2),
                      cartItems[index].distributorName = item[extractorValue],
                      cartItems[index].distributorId =  item[external_Id],
                      setCartItems(cartItems)
                    )
              }}
              />
            </View>
          )
    }

    const removeFromCart = (id) =>{
        let updatedCart = cartItems.filter(product => product?.products?.Id !== id)
        setCartItems(updatedCart)
        ToastAndroid.show('Item Removed From the Cart.', ToastAndroid.SHORT)
        if(updatedCart.length === 0){
          navigation.goBack()
        }
    }
    
    const submitHandler = () =>{
      setLoading(true)
      createOrders(cartItems, valueSchemeFromDropDown)
    }

    const reduceHandler = (item, index) =>{
      if(item.qty === 1){
          let newResults = cartItems.filter(product => product.products.Id !== item.products.Id)
          setCartItems(newResults)
          if(newResults.length === 0){
            navigation.goBack()
          }
      }
      else{
          item.qty = item.qty - 1
          let newResults = cartItems.filter(product => product.products.Id !== item.products.Id ? product : item)
          setCartItems(newResults)
      }
  }
  const [testValue, setTestValue] = React.useState('')
  const [testFocus, setTestFocus] = React.useState(false)

  const incrementHandler = (item, index) =>{
        let newResults = cartItems.map(product => 
        product.products.Id === item.products.Id ? {...item, qty: product.qty + 1} : product)
        setCartItems(newResults)
    }
  return (
    <>
      { loading  ? 
      <RowCenter style={{flex:1, flexDirection: 'column', alignItems:'center'}}>
        <StyledText fontSize={'20px'}>{createOrderStatus ? 'Redirecting..' : 'Loading..'}</StyledText>
      </RowCenter> :
      <>
      <View style={{flex:0.8}}>
      <ScrollView showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}>
        {cartItems?.map((item, index)=>{
          return(
            <View key={item?.products?.Id} style={{flexDirection:'row', padding:13, borderRadius:10, margin:10, alignItems:'center', backgroundColor:COLORS.green20, ...customShadow }}>
                <View style={{width:'100%'}}>
                    <StyledText>Product Name : {item?.products?.Name}</StyledText>
                    <ExtraSpace />
                    {item?.products?.Description &&
                      <StyledText>Product Description : {item?.products?.Description?.length > 30 ? item?.products?.Description?.slice(0,30) + '...': item?.products?.Description }</StyledText>
                    }
                    <ExtraSpace />
                    <View style={{flexDirection:'row', justifyContent:'space-between', alignItems:'center', padding:10}}>
                        <TouchableOpacity onPress={()=>removeFromCart(item?.products?.Id)} style={{flexDirection:'row', justifyContent:'center', alignItems:'center'}}>
                            <SimpleLineIcons name="trash" size={15} color={COLORS.error} />
                            <StyledText color={COLORS.error}>Remove</StyledText>
                        </TouchableOpacity>
                        <View style={{width:'40%', flexDirection:'row', justifyContent:'space-between', alignItems:'center',}}>
                        <TouchableOpacity onPress={()=>reduceHandler(item, index)}>
                          <Feather name="minus-circle" size={22} color={COLORS.gray90} />
                        </TouchableOpacity>
                        <StyledText>Qty : {item?.qty}</StyledText>
                        <TouchableOpacity onPress={()=>incrementHandler(item, index)} >
                            <Feather name="plus-circle" size={22} color={COLORS.gray90} />
                        </TouchableOpacity>
                        </View>
                    </View>
                    <RenderDropDown index={index} text={'Distributor'} data={distributors?.response} external_Id='external_Id' extractorValue='name' />
                    {item.distributorName &&
                      <Label color={'#131821'}> Clone Selected : {item.distributorName}</Label>
                    }
                    <RenderDropDown id={item?.products?.id} index={index} text={'Quantity Scheme'} data={schemes?.response?.filter(scheme => scheme.Type__c === 'Quantity Scheme')} external_Id='Id' extractorValue='Name' qtyScheme={true}/>
                </View>
            </View>
          )
        })} 
      </ScrollView>
      </View>
      <View style={{flex:0.2, justifyContent:'center', alignItems:'center', borderWidth:1, borderTopLeftRadius:10, borderTopRightRadius:10, marginBottom:2, marginHorizontal:1, borderTopColor:'gray', backgroundColor:"transparent"}}>
          <DropdownComponent text={'Value Scheme'} data={schemes?.response?.filter(scheme => scheme.Type__c === 'Value Scheme')} external_Id='Id' extractorValue={'Name'} value={testValue} setValue={setTestValue} isFocus={testFocus} setIsFocus={setTestFocus} extraStyling={{width: '100%', marginTop:10, marginBottom:1}}/> 
          {/* <RenderDropDown text={'Value Scheme'} data={valueScheme} external_Id='Id' extractorValue='Name' valueScheme={true}/> */}
          <TextButton onPress={()=>{cartItems?.length === 0 ? null : submitHandler()}} componentStyling={{width:'94%', padding:8, marginHorizontal:10, marginBottom:10, marginTop:1}} title='Place Order'/>
      </View>
      </>
    }
    </>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hey you have added these

```
 onFocus={() => setIsFocus(true)}
        onBlur={() => setIsFocus(false)}
```

and these are setStates , so it will re render when dropdwon opens or closes

Hope it helps.  feel free for doubts

Comment: tried changing what you have said , not working brother still having the same issue